# Is it possible to create a slider for Conway's game of life if birth happens only when there are FOUR living neighbours?

Tags: math, conways-game-of-life, cellular-automata

I'm just playing around with Conway's game of life and I adjusted the settings so that birth only happens when there are 4 living neighbours. A cell will die when the living neighbours != 2.

After a lot of trying I still can't find a slider, is this probably just impossible?!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a Life-like cellular automaton where births require at least four live neighbors cannot have gliders.

To see why, take any isolated cluster of live cells on the lattice and draw a box around it.  Now observe that any cell outside the box has at most three neighboring cells that are inside the box.  This means that the cluster of cells inside the box can never move or expand outside the box.